# Values not being sent in POST request to API (Postman + Strapi)

Tags: javascript, json, postman, strapi

Im trying to POST an entry to Strapi through Postman. I have three fields in my endpoint, which are boxname + boxlocation + boxnumber. Two first are string and the last is integer. But for some reason my values doesnt get posted, they all turn up as null.

Any idea why? I ended up using Postman to try, because my Javascript wouldn't work either:

```
async function pushToStrapi(token, boxname, boxlocation, ownerid) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "http://localhost:1337/boxes";
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
  };
  var data = JSON.stringify({"boxname": ""+boxname+"", "boxlocation": ""+boxlocation+"" }});
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

[image: As you can see, Im trying to POST an entry through the API endpoint of Strapi through Postman.]

Comment: Can you show how you handel your request?

Comment: Beqause in the picture you are sending yor data as a `GET` not as a `POST`

Comment: If it is POST , then why sending data as query params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a syntax error. Change:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({"boxname": ""+boxname+"", "boxlocation": ""+boxlocation+"" }});
```

To:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({"boxname": ""+boxname+"", "boxlocation": ""+boxlocation+"" });
```

If you prefer to use shorthand, you can do something like this:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify({boxname, boxlocation});
```

Comment: Wow, embarassing. Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this kind of request.

You will have to click on "body" then select the "raw" format and choose "JSON" in the format drop down.

Then in write your JSON object w/ your key values.

You can not send params in query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue too, I'm learning Strapi, and in my case I was sending the ID in the JSON Object, wich is managed by Strapi, then I removed the ID (autoincremental value) and send only the data. In your example I see that you don't send the ID field, but this point maybe can help you or others who read.

This is my request:

```
{
"post_name": "raw postman post",
"post_description":"raw postman post",
"post_content": "raw postman post",
"post_category": 1 }
```

And this is the response that worked:

```
{
"id": 9,
"post_name": "raw postman post",
"post_description": "raw postman post",
"post_content": "raw postman post",
"post_category": {
    "id": 1,
    "category_name": "Climate",
    "category_desc": "Climate",
    "published_at": "2020-10-16T11:37:11.931Z",
    "created_at": "2020-10-16T11:35:01.418Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-16T11:37:11.950Z"
},
"published_at": "2020-10-22T11:35:59.714Z",
"created_at": "2020-10-22T11:35:59.722Z",
"updated_at": "2020-10-22T11:35:59.731Z"}
```